# supplementaire attributes in many to many relationship jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, attributes

I have a little problem. I try to represent a relationship with pojo and jpa to the following mapping:

```
table A :
id_a (PK)
nom_a

table B :
id_b (PK)
nom_b

intermediate table :
id_a(PK), id_b(PK)
quantity
```

and my intermediate table contains a composite key `id_a(PK), id_b(PK).`

I would like my modeling allows me:
when I delete an item from the table a or table b would require the element of the intermediate table is deleted by waterfall

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: clearly you need to have classes to represent anything in JPA, so where do you think this "extra attribute" will be stored?

Comment: i want to stored in new join table "intermediate table"

Comment: I can create an association class where I put the primary keys of both tables and supplimentaireS attributeS with two relationship 1. * Two side.
but I want utilser the true principles of JPA.

Comment: I asked about the CLASSES, not the TABLES. You CANNOT have a M-N relation with supplementary attributes in Java classes ... you can have 1-N relations, with some INTERMEDIATE CLASS, then N-1 to the other class. This has been asked many times on this site.

Comment: @isom the "true principles of JPA" do include using intermediate classes for join tables that have supplementary data. Yes, you can use just annotations to define the join tables corresponding to `@ManyToMany` associations, but that is not possible when there is supplementary data in the join table.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an intermediate entity with this supplementary field and bidirectional references to both entities. This entity shall reference the base entities through the `@ManyToOne` relationship, and the base entities shall reference this intermediate entity through the `@OneToMany` relationship.

The `cascade` attribute for `@OneToMany` references should be set to CascadeType.REMOVE, if you want this intermediate entity to be automatically removed whenever you delete any of the connected items.

Here's the sample mapping (getters and setters omitted):

```
@Entity
public class FirstEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "firstEntity", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<IntermediateEntity> intermediates = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class SecondEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "secondEntity", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<IntermediateEntity> intermediates = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class IntermediateEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Long quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "first_entity_id")
    private FirstEntity firstEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "second_entity_id")
    private SecondEntity secondEntity;
}
```